# How to render React component with passed props from server and also binded event handlers?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

I make a GET API call on the server and recieve some data. I return the HTML and React components with passed props.

I want to bind event handlers, so I have to re-render it on the client side, but this overwrites (in this case deletes) all of my passed props.

Is there a solution? (beside making the API call on the client side)

Comment: You should add your codes and the codes you already tried so far.

Comment: Use arrow functions instead on binding them. Can you add attempt code so that it will be helpful to understand exact problem

Comment: You may need to use `hydrate` instead of `render`: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate